# File is not visible when phone sd card is connected to pc

Tags: java, android

I created an excel file from android,when I connect my phone to computer , then in computer I am unable to see that file. Why is that?

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Cell c = null;

    //Cell style for header row
    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();

    //New Sheet
    Sheet sheet1 = null;
    sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Meter Readings");

    // Generate column headings
    Row row = sheet1.createRow(1);

    c = row.createCell(0);
    c.setCellValue("Flat Number");
    c.setCellStyle(cs);

    sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 200));

    // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),fileName);
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(os);
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file);
        success = true;
        //os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != os) {
                os.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are your logs saying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your phone or reconnect again to your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the rply, Is there no other option to do Girish?

Comment: Can you please restart your device and check ?

Comment: Yeah I do restart it is visible , but I don't want to do that . Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: i don't think so , probably you can share excel sheet to google drive thru your android app programatically :)

Comment: Instead of restart use this code "MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {file.toString()}, null, null);" it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be lack of permissions to write the file

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

It also could be that the external storage isn't mounted, check with:

```
Environent.getExternalStorageState();
```

Answer (score 0):

PC's file explorer didn't refresh Android file system immediately.

So I recommand you to use `adb shell` command. It will show immediately changes of your device's file system like this.

1. `$ adb devices`
   // Get your device ID. If you connect one only, this command isn't necessary.
2. `$ adb shell (-s your-device-id)`
   // Enter to file system of your device.
3. `shell$ cd sdcard/`
   // In common case, the path of default device storage is `/sdcard`. Change directory then find your file.
4. `shell$ exit` // If you found the file, exit `adb shell`.
5. `$ adb pull /sdcard/<parent-directory-path>/<file-name> <destination-path-on-your-PC>` // If you need to get this file on your system, use this command.

If you can't find, the file may not have been created. In this case, you will check the project settings as below:

1. Set `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` if your app support under API 19.
2. Implement `RuntimePermission` routine if your app support over API 21.

   According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html?hl=en), permission will be granted while app is running on Android 6.0 or higher.

   For implementation, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651771/file-createnewfile-method-throws-exception-in-android-m) to refer the sample code.